# Find server details about where the WebSphere MQ Queue Manager has been configured

Tags: websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

I need help in finding the server details about where the WebSphere MQ Queue Manager has been configured. In WAS console I see a queue manager name in the connection properties, but I don't know in which server the queue manager is configured. Is there a way to find out the details?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created WMQ on WAS , you should be able to find it in the Queue Connection Factories. You should find that under JMS and look at Connection Factories / Queue Connection Factories to see the host and port of the configured WMQ server

[image]

Comment: But am not seeing the server name where the queue manager is configured ?

Comment: You'll see the hostname of the server or possibly the IP address of it. What do you see in the Hostname and Port fields of the above screenshot?